# Jenkins rebuild old build job with its associated git revision id

Tags: jenkins

How to rebuild old build job with its associated git revision id for rollback purpose or deploying old/selected build id to different environments using declarative  pipeline ?

Cheers

Comment: Could you please describe your setup?

Comment: 1 declarative pipeline with stage 1 (clone repo), stage 2 (build code i.e create zip) stage 2 (deploy using zip).  Each time build job runs it clones the latest git revision(i have single master branch). I want to update the pipeline code so that i can select any old build id and rebuild it using the git revision id used by that old build id so that stage 1 clones/checkout with the old git revision id and create zip accordingly ; which will accomplish deploy step to rollback to previous state.  I have tried the 'ReBuild plugin' but it always clones the latest commit id.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! used Git Parameter, took ref from : `https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do is probably to create a branch from that commit id and build that branch

Comment: Say I have approx. 10 old buid jobs in my pipeline history. And I want to choose build no. 7; to restore to previous state -  how would i choose commit id of build no 7 and rebuild job 7 ? NOTE: I will be to providing the build url of the pipeline to end users so that they can perform restore of any old bulid when required by a single click.

Comment: usually when you open the build, there will be a commit id mentioned there. You can then create a branch from that build `git branch name commitid` then push. If you use multibranch pipeline, just make sure the branch is built. If you use the regular pipeline, you may need to create another job with the proper branch. But all of this will not be "a single click", if you need that